# Race condition with $http in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, service

I have the following service:

```
app.factory('ParserWebService', function($http, $q, $timeout){
    ParserWebService.getParserPfList = function() {

        var pfData = $q.defer();
        var pfList = [];

        $http.get("https://myurl/parserpf")
            .then(function(response) {

                var reponseDataJSON = JSON.parse(response.data);

                for (var el in reponseDataJSON) {
                    if (reponseDataJSON[el].pf.length > 0) {  // Check for non-empty string
                        pfList.push(reponseDataJSON[el]);
                    }
                }
console.log("http GET SUCCESS");
console.log("pfList.length: " + pfList.length);

            })
            .catch(function(response) {
                console.error('GET error', response.status, response.data);
            })

console.log(pfList[0]);

        $timeout(function(){
            pfData.resolve(pfList);
        },1000);

console.log("pfList.length: " + pfList.length);
console.log("pfData.promise.length: " + pfData.promise.length);
        return pfData.promise;
    }

  return ParserWebService;
});
```

When I am calling it, I first get the error because the service returns nothing according to console printouts just before return (see below in). Only after that I see printout on the console that $http was success and the pfList.lenght is 109 (see below).

```
pfList.length: 0            <------------------
pfData.promise.length: undefined        <----------------
mopidId = 0, id = null
angular.js:11607 TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (controllers.js:32)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4185)
    at $get.w.instance (angular.js:8454)
    at angular.js:7700
    at s (angular.js:331)
    at A (angular.js:7699)
    at g (angular.js:7078)
    at g (angular.js:7081)
    at g (angular.js:7081)
    at angular.js:6957(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11607$get @ angular.js:8557$get.l.$apply @ angular.js:14502(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1448e @ angular.js:4185d @ angular.js:1446tc @ angular.js:1466Jd @ angular.js:1360(anonymous function) @ angular.js:26176m.Callbacks.j @ jquery.js:3148m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.js:3260m.extend.ready @ jquery.js:3472J @ jquery.js:3503
models.js:599 http GET SUCCESS   <---------------
models.js:600 pfList.length: 109  <---------------
```

Seems like a race condition here. Why is this happening and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: typical javascript (without any sort of workers) runs in a single thread, I don't think it's related to race condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making things unnecessarily complicated.

`$http` returns a promise itself, so just return that from the function and you won't need to the `$q` or the weird timeout. See below

```
app.factory('ParserWebService', function($http){
    ParserWebService.pfList=[];

    ParserWebService.getParserPfList = function() {

        return $http.get("https://myurl/parserpf")
            .then(function(response) {

                var reponseDataJSON = JSON.parse(response.data);

                for (var el in reponseDataJSON) {
                    if (reponseDataJSON[el].pf.length > 0) {  // Check for non-empty string
                        ParserWebService.pfList.push(reponseDataJSON[el]);
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch(function(response) {
                console.error('GET error', response.status, response.data);
            })
    }

  return ParserWebService;
});
```

The reason the first `console.log` had no data was because it wasn't in the `then` block so it executes before the `$http` call has chance to finish.

If you were using the above code to chain events you'd use it like so

```
ParserWebService.getParserPfList.then(function(){
    console.log("All the data is here: ",ParserWebService.pfList);
})
```

---

If you are certain on making the promise return the data in the function you could alter your code like so:

```
ParserWebService.getParserPfList = function() {

    var pfData = $q.defer();
    var pfList = [];

    $http.get("https://myurl/parserpf")
        .then(function(response) {

            var reponseDataJSON = JSON.parse(response.data);

            for (var el in reponseDataJSON) {
                if (reponseDataJSON[el].pf.length > 0) {  // Check for non-empty string
                    pfList.push(reponseDataJSON[el]);
                }
            }
            pfData.resolve(pfList);

        })
        .catch(function(response) {
            console.error('GET error', response.status, response.data);
            pfData.reject();
        })

    return pfData.promise;
}
```

Final note: if you specify to the http call that you expect JSON you won't need to parse it afterwards